# hide jQuery table row

Tags: php, jquery, html-table, hide

I've got a search done with jQuery..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<div style="width:400px; margin:auto;">
<form action="clientes.php" method="post">
  <legend>Procurar cliente</legend>
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>" style="width: 280px; height: 23px;" /><input type="button" name="btnPesquisar" value="Pesquisar" onclick="getDados();"/></form>
</div>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

and getDados returns the results from another page, which is:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include "conexao.php";
if ($_GET['nome']) { 
$nome = $_GET['nome'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nome LIKE '%".$nome."%' OR cpf LIKE     '%".$nome."%' ORDER BY nome ASC") or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 
}

if ($num_rows != 0) {
?>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">    </script></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.hideme td').hide();
});
</script>
<table border=4 width="800px" align="center">
<tr><th>Cliente</th> <th>CPF</th> <th>Telefone</th> <th> Aniversário </th><th> Endereço </th></tr>
<?php
$i = "1";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

<TR>
<td width="220px" align="center"> <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['nomepost<?php echo $i; ?>'].submit();"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></a> </td>
<td width="80px" align="center"> <?php echo $row['cpf']; ?> </td>
<td width="120px" align="center"><?php echo $row['telefone'] ?> </td>
<td width="120px" align="center"><?php echo $row['dataNascimento']; ?></a></td>
<td width="270px" align="center"><?php echo $row['endereco']; ?></td>
</TR>
<tr class="hideme"><td><form id="nomepost<?php echo $i; ?>" action="agrupaclienteteste.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="nome" value="<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>"></form></td</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
}
else{
if ($nome) { echo "Não há dados cadastrados em nosso sistema."; }
}
?>
```

Now.. the thing is, if I run the page of the results by itself.. lets say 
    result.php?nome=I

it hides the tr class=hideme...
if I access the search page and search for nome = I, it shows the results but it doesn't hide the tr class=hideme ...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing what getDados does. Does it make an ajax request or does it move the browser location on to the result page? If it makes an ajax request, what are you doing to have the response get interpreted by the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just use `style="display:none;"` as attribute value, since you are trying to hide onload itself